# Powershell: counting unique strings via hash table

Tags: powershell, hashtable, unique

An "it works -- but is it a best practice?" question. In Perl there's a compact way of keeping track of occurrences of, say, strings found within a file: store them in a hash table. For example:

```
$HashTable{'the string in question'}++;
```

Perl increments the value for key `the string in question` as many times as this is done. It ensures unique "hits" at the same time that it keeps track of occurrences. Just hacking around, I found I could do much the same with Powershell:

`$HashTable['a']++` or even
`$Hashtable.a++` (which kind of surprised me -- or even)
`$Hashtable."this is a key"++`

Ok, so it works. But is there an approach in Powershell that's considered a better practice?

Comment: Oh, nice. It didn't occur to me that that could work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach looks quite good, at least for PowerShell with its helpers for hashtables. Just keep in mind that hashtables defined as `@{}` are case insensitive. If you need a case sensitive hashtable then create it like `New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable`.

Example:

```
# case insensitive
$hash = @{}
$hash['a']++
$hash['A']++
$hash

'------------------------'

# case sensitive
$hash = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable
$hash['a']++
$hash['A']++
$hash
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              2
------------------------
a                              1
A                              1
```

In C# using `Dictionary<string, int>` is probably a "better practice". It is also possible in PowerShell but it unlikely makes things much "better" in PowerShell.

A PowerShell-ish solution is probably use of `Group-Object -NoElement`. Is it a better approach or practice? I do not know. It depends on a few factors including preferences. Here is the example:

```
'a', 'A', 'foo', 'foo' , 'bar' | Group-Object -NoElement
```

Output:

```
Count Name
----- ----
    2 a
    2 foo
    1 bar
```

Comment: Great answer -- thanks. The for-the-newbie books I've been reading have not yet covered case-sensitivity in hash tables and that's extremely useful to know. (When I think of 'best' practice I'm thinking: clear enough to understand at first glance, consistent with the language (IOW, not some terrible hack), and _maintainable_.)